# Collect more than one symbol and series

Tags: polynomials, series-expansion

I have a complicated expression in function of 2 variables A and f that appears in all the possible combination. 
For example

```
a A^2 f + Tanh[c d] A f^2 +A^2 f^2 + 3 A f^3+ ....
```

and so on. 
I need to do a Series of this expression, neglecting

```
O(A^2 f^2).
```

I tried to **Collect** and then **Series**, but didn't work out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a well-defined question in the absence of further information. So I'll make some assumptions.

If $A$ and $f$ are the "same kind of small", then we can set $A=A_0x$ and $f=f_0x$, then series-expand in $x$:

```
Q = a A^2 f + Tanh[c d] A f^2 + A^2 f^2 + 3 A f^3;
Series[Q /. {A -> A0 x, f -> f0 x}, {x, 0, 3}]
```

> $$
> \left(a A_0^2 f_0+A_0 f_0^2 \tanh (c d)\right)x^3+O\left(x^4\right)
> $$

From this, the expression with higher-order terms dropped can be found with

```
Normal[%] /. {x -> 1, A0 -> A, f0 -> f}
```

> $$
> a A^2 f + A f^2 \tanh(c d)
> $$

If, on the other hand, $A$ is much smaller than $f$, we can for example set

```
Series[Q /. {A -> A0 x^2, f -> f0 x}, {x, 0, 5}]
```

> $$
> f_0^2 x^4 \tanh (c d)+x^5 \left(a A_0^2 f_0+3 A_0
>    f_0^3\right)+O\left(x^6\right)
> $$

```
Normal[%] /. {x -> 1, A0 -> A, f0 -> f}
```

> $$
> a A^2 f + 3 A f^3 + A f^2 \tanh(c d)
> $$

If, on the third hand, $f$ is much smaller than $A$, we can for example set

```
Series[Q /. {A -> A0 x, f -> f0 x^2}, {x, 0, 5}]
```

> $$
> a A_0^2 f_0 x^4+A_0 f_0^2 x^5 \tanh (c d)+O\left(x^6\right)
> $$

```
Normal[%] /. {x -> 1, A0 -> A, f0 -> f}
```

> $$
> a A^2 f + A f^2 \tanh(c d)
> $$

So you see it really depends on the relationship between $A$ and $f$. Many more relationships are possible, the above three examples are not exhaustive!

Comment: The first assumption was the right one, they are the same kind of small, sorry I forgot to specify!

Comment: @rob if they are the same kind of small, then you could also just substitute `f -> y*A` and then series-expand in `A`, and at the end back-substitute `y -> f/A`.